# How to get all php parameters from url?

Tags: php

I am trying to get php parameters from a url.  The parameters can be anyting, the url could be http://example.com/?foo=bar&trees=cool&owl=wow or the url could be http://example.com/index.php?chickens=dead.  I want it to cycle through the url and get the values. I want to get each value to execute the code **$_GET['value from ur'] = what it equals;** in a for loop.

*Any help is appreciated, also I researched this and there was no answer to be found.  Please don't mark it as a duplicate.*

Comment: See the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) on the php manual, then use explode or what you want to build an associative array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_GET` is an array, iterate over it using for each

```
foreach($_GET as $query_string_variable => $value) {
   echo "$query_string_variable  = $value <Br />";
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed for my site! Thanks so much!

Comment: you just messed up with the accepted answers! So you put a tick to the answer which suits you the best, to others you can click the up arrow button to upvote ;)

Comment: Should be fixed. Not used to accepting answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_GET as $k => $v)
   echo $k . ' - ' . $v . '<br />';
```

Comment: This is also what I needed for my site! Thanks!